# Creating django management commands

Tags: django, django-admin, python-2.7

I want to run a command which is something like this, but the function `handle (self,*args,**options)` doesn't seem to execute the nested functions.

How can I include my functions inside `handle()`?

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        def hello():
            print "hello1"
        def hello1():
            print "hello2"
```

Comment: You must 'call' the functions after their definitions in order to execute them: hello(); hello1()

Answer (score 3):

You can also define functions 'on the fly':

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self):
        def hello():
            print "hello1"

        def hello1():
            print "hello2"

        hello()
        hello1()
```

or outside the command (as they where 'service' functions):

```
def hello():
    print "hello1"

def hello1():
    print "hello2"


class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    def handle_noargs(self):
        hello()
        hello1()
```

Comment: :hey thanks a lot.. it really helped....one more doubt....if i want to call a function that takes an argument from command line then how i am i supposed to do that ????.Do i have to use class Command or some other class.

Comment: Yes, you must extend BaseCommand and use 'handle' method. See here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands) for two ways to have arguments: "*args" or "option_list"